# Changing the highlighted cell in tableview after variable time interval

Tags: ios, swift, timer, tableview

I have to highlight the first cell of tableview on play button click and then i have an array of time interval at which the cell highlighted keeps on changing at that time interval.Any solution help pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this :

```
var lastSelectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

func viewDidLoad() {
     Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timerFunc), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
@objc func timerFunc() {
    if lastSelectedIndexPath != nil {
        tableView(self.table, didUnhighlightRowAt: lastSelectedIndexPath!)
    }
    tableView(self.table, didHighlightRowAt: IndexPath(row: YOUR_ROW, section: YOUR_SECTION))
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    lastSelectedIndexPath = indexPath
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this question based on my understanding of this question. You are suppose to highlight tableview cell after some time duration.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];


- (void)targetMethod {
NSIndexPath *defaultIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:Any_Row_Number inSection:Any_Section_Number];
[self tableView:[self tableView] didSelectRowAtIndexPath:defaultIndexPath];
}
```